# jQuery AJAX request getting response but no callbacks are fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have code as such:

```
$.ajax({
     method: "GET",
     url: page,
     dataType: 'html',
     data:data,
     success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
     },
     error: function(){
        console.log('error');
     }
 });
```

Using either Chrome or Firefox's debugger I can see that the request is successful with a response of 200 OK and the response contains the expected data.
My problem is, however, that no callbacks fire whatsoever. "Success" does not fire nor does "Error". Furthermore, no deferred methods fire either, such as "done", "then", or "always".

I've been trying to trouble shoot this for the past few hours to no avail. I'm at a total loss. I've also tried using methods such as "$.get" with the same result.

In short, I'm getting the response, but the code in jQuery is not firing any callbacks and all without any visible errors in the console.

Comment: Try binding an always callback (http://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/) and see if that fires.

Comment: As I said in my initial post, no deferred methods including "always" are firing. The ajax request does successfully occur though.

Comment: success and error are deprecated, unless you're using an older version of jQuery. If on a recent version, you might want to consider hooking .done and .fail instead.

Comment: check this jsfiddle out :http://jsfiddle.net/6GHpu/4/  As much as I can see the callback does fire

Comment: @NeilCresswell - the `success` and `error` callback functions are NOT deprecated.  What is deprecated is `.success()`  the method (replaced by `.done()`), not the callback the OP is using.

Comment: In any case, neither the "success" callback nor the "done" method are being called at all. For what it's worth, this code is running for an IDX Broker page, however it is not cross-domain. Also, the call is made from within a browserify module.

Comment: Are you 100% sure it's not cross domain because that is the most likely cause of not getting an `error` callback?  A common mistake is for the page and ajax request to different slightly in the domain (like one is `www.example.com` and the other is `example.com` or one is `https` and the other is not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I see wrong in your code is that:

```
method: "GET",
```

should be:

```
type: "GET",
```

I don't see any documented property for `method` in the jQuery doc.  The `type` property is supposed to default to `"GET"` so this may not be the only thing wrong here.

---

In addition, there are cases where the `error` callback will not be called even if the ajax call fails (in cross-domain requests).  From the jQuery doc for the `error` callback:

> This handler is not called for cross-domain script and cross-domain JSONP requests.

This is because jQuery is expecting the server to send back a particular form of javascript and if the server doesn't do what is expected, then jQuery never knows when the request comes back and can't process it.

In these cases, you often have to figure out what might be going wrong from looking at the network trace in the debugger.

---

Other things to check to make sure you aren't accidentally cross domain:

- Make sure the domain/subdomain are exactly the same between ajax call and the page.  For example, one common mistake is for one to have `www.` on it and the other not.
- Make both page and ajax URL are both same `http` or `https`.
- If using a non-standard port number, make sure both page and ajax URL are using the same port.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. Unfortunately this hasn't resolved my problem either. The request is from a script hosted at another domain but the script is linked through the HTML at the other domain. Perhaps, that counts as cross-domain in this instance. But the request does occur successfully as shown in Chrome network tab, but the callbacks are never executed.

Comment: @JohnnyThrash - Do you understand that if jQuery thinks the request is cross domain, it will expect a JSONP response from the server (which is a script that gets executed).  You may see what you're expecting to see in the network tab, but if it's not formatted as a JSONP script, it simply won't work and you will get no callbacks.  This seems the most likely culprit to me.  What is the EXACT URL of the HTML page showing in the browser?  What is the EXACT URL of the ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

The following code works. Also note that AJAX will not work with cross site scripting.
If you want to get the error you can print the "errorThrown"

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#getLink').on("click", function () {
            var url = $("#myUrl");
            alert(url.val());
            $.ajax({

                type: "GET",
                url: url.val(),
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                    $("#data").text(textStatus);
                },
                error: function (data,textStatus, errorThrown){
                    $("#data").text(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        });

    });

</script>

<input id="myUrl" name="myURL" type="text" value="http://localhost:35460/Home/TestPage.cshtml" />
<input type="button" value="getLink" id="getLink">
<span id="data"></span>
```

Comment: How is this an answer to the OP's problem?